# Selenium Webdriver/Java- Wait function and error handling

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, wait

I'm writing automated tests using Selenium WebDriver and Java that need lots of Waits in them to make sure that the appropriate element has loaded before the next action is taken.

I've tried this:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

which will wait for a specified interval and then fail if the element is not found,

And this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 100);
wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
  public Boolean apply(WebDriver webDriver) {
    System.out.println("Searching for the Companies dropdown");
    return webDriver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_PageContent_vpccompanies_Input")) != null;
  }
});
```

which will hang indefinitely if the element is not found,

What I'd like is something that would search for the element for a couple of tries and then fail with an error message.

Comment: Didn't you satisfied with the answers here? Please accept answers.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code onto a cycle and loop until the find condition matched or extra condition that exits a loop. 
Use `isElementPresent(element)` to check that condition of find.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, put `your element access code`  in a while loop, which breaks either on `success` or `number of attempts`.

e.g.**(pseudo code)**

```
    int numAttemps = 0;
    int specifiedAttempts = 5;
    boolean success = false;
    do{
       numAttemps++;
       try{
         //access the element
          WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(..));
          success  = true; //<--If it reaches here means success
       }catch(NoSuchElementException nse)
           //one attempt failed
       }
     }while(!success || numAttemps <specifiedAttempts);

     if(!success){
        System.out.println("Couldn't load after " +specifiedAttempts+ " attempts");
     }
```

Comment: this doesnt help much in most cases. situation like slow response from server and etc; also, writting a loop to retry tasks is memory consuming